# How to make Tamil fonts work in a chat client?

Tags: fonts, ibus

Please tell me how to enable Tamil fonts in Chat client. I already have the newest version of IBus in 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

Search for *Keyboard input methods* in the dash and open it.

Go to *Input method* tab and click on *Select an Input method*. Scroll down to Tamil and you will have a couple of options to install. I have Phonetic installed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi - if you are happy with the answer - please click the tick symbol next to this answer to accept it.  Thanks!